# Optimize query with MAX (id)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, max

I have this query that shows me the last `id` by `id_units`, depending on the date.

My query is:

```
SELECT max(swg.id) AS id
 FROM swg
 WHERE swg.status != 0
 AND sg.dateswg <= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY('2015-12-28')),'2015-12-28')
 GROUP BY swg.id_units
ORDER BY swg.id;
```

The query returns more than 2000 records, I think that there is a way that I can performance this query.

I am trying to performance my query like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT * FROM swg WHERE status != 0 AND dateswg <= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY('2015-12-28')),'2015-12-28') ORDER BY id_units, id desc) x
GROUP BY id_units;
```

It is works, but I would like to know if there is another way to improve it

Regard!

Comment: Do you have any index ?

Comment: Do `ORDER BY id` instead, to make the query correct!

Comment: No I don´t have @Prdp

Comment: What is `id_production_unit_detail`?  What is `sg`?  Please fix those and any other typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT max(swg.id) AS id
FROM swg
WHERE swg.status <> 0 AND
      swg.dateswg <= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 6 - WEEKDAY('2015-12-28'), '2015-12-28')
GROUP BY swg.id_units
ORDER BY MAX(swg.id);
```

This is tricky to optimize, because an index cannot be used for both conditions.  You can start with a composite index on all four columns used in the query: `swg(dateswg, status, id_units, id)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am going to review how I can do it°

Answer (score 0):

Of `status` is only either `0` or `1`, then change to `status = 1` so that the Optimizer has one place to look, not two disjoint places.  Then have

```
INDEX(status, dateswg, id_units, id) -- in this order.
```

That will be pretty good for the `WHERE` and will be "covering".

Unfortunately both the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY` will need a sort; the latter one will be 2000 rows, and probably be done in RAM; I can't tell about the former.